# How to add two encoding type together as parameter while xml parsing?

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

One xml file has encoding type UTF-16 and another has UTF-8. After taking input of two files I want to parse it together, How to add two encoding type?

```
tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
xml_data = tree.getroot()
xmlstr = ET.tostring(xml_data, encoding='utf-8/UTF-16', method='xml')
data_dict = dict(xmltodict.parse(xmlstr))
```

Comment: You have to realise that having a text with 2 different encodings makes no sense. That's like writing a text that is simultanouesly in English and Chinese.

Comment: No, it is actually a folder that has two different types of encoded xml files.

Comment: I'm speaking about this part: `ET.tostring(xml_data, encoding='utf-8/UTF-16', method='xml')`. This has nothing to do with files, whose encoding is decided when you create `xmlFile` object.

Comment: Setting `encoding='utf-8/UTF-16'` won't work. It's just strange. What do you expect to accomplish with something like that?